# How to convolve an audio with an impulse response?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, convolution

I want to convolve speech files with the impulse response.

Let say on average the speech files have a duration of ten seconds. I am trying to do the convolution using `numpy` or `scipy` libraries.

When I try I am getting memory error! I am sorry that I can't provide the speech file and impulse response here. Please use any audio files to check this.

```
import numpy as np
convolved_speech_data = np.convolve(speech_data, impulse_response)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
return multiarray.correlate(a, v[::-1], mode)
MemoryError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't know why this throws error, do I need to normalize the audio before convolving or do I have to use windowing?

Comment: What's the shape of both your `speech_data` and `impulse_response`? I.e. the output of `speech_data.shape` and `impulse_response.shape`.

Comment: @blubberdiblub Thank you, your clue got rid of the above error. But after convolution, the audio is clipped. Do you know how can I get rid of this?

Comment: Um, I wasn't aware that I gave a clue :) I honestly just asked for more information. Depends on what you mean by clipped. Do you mean there's something missing at the beginning or end? Or are you referring to "clipping" where there's audible distortion or crackles?

Comment: The problem was the impulse response was saved as a double mono, so there was a mismatch with the shape. What I meant by clipping is, the convoluted audio is having way more amplitude than the original one! It looks like the whole audio is just amplified by a certain target level! But there is no audible distortion.

Comment: To adjust the volume, you may want to divide by `np.sqrt((impulse_response**2).sum())` or something similar, as the convolution doesn't involve some division step by itself. The formula is just "by instinct" and may be incorrect. Also, even after that you may still have peaks that go above your original extrema. Normalization would be an option, as would be "compression".

Comment: do you mean normalizing the impulse response with the maximum integer it can represent?

Comment: No, I meant normalizing the result signal, if even after the division step I suggested you still have peaks that are problematic ("clipping"). Or alternatively (dynamic range) compression.

Comment: Actually, it's likely dividing by `impulse_response.sum()` instead of the earlier formula. That works when I try it with a sine source signal and actual IR values as opposed to the random values I used earlier. Just dividing by the sum is also consistent with what I've seen done on image filtering convolutions.

Comment: @blubberdiblub Thank you, I will try and let you know whether it works for me.